# Django 1.9 DateTime Filter

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-1.9

I'm attempting to filter a model that contains the field below:

```
TEMP_START = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

And I'm using the syntax

```
x.filter(TEMP_START__date = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 8, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>))
```

However, this returns multiple unique TEMP_START values. I am thinking this is due to my data being stored without time zones. But, I have set in my settings.py file:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' # 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I am unsure why other unique datetime object values are being returned by this filter statement. I am aware the "__date" filter is new to Django 1.9. Is this just a bug?

Comment: What TEMP_START values are returned in your example?

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 8, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)` appears to be invalid syntax. What is the exact syntax you're using?

Comment: The syntax is invalid due to the tzinfo. None of my data is localized.

Comment: @evert Start Summary: {'TEMP_START__date': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 14, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}  << This is what the filter is on________________________                                                          
[{'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 2, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 8, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 20, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 14, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the relevant information directly into your question, not in a comment. You should also make sure you use correct syntax, so that people can copy-paste your example code. Symbolic representation with `<UTC>` is *not* correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the

```
__contains
```

keyword seemed to offer the best result and I haven't had issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

The `__date` field look-up works on *dates* (only), as its name suggests. Not on date-time objects; time is ignored.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date), and in particular the example, also show this:

> For datetime fields, casts the value as date. Allows chaining additional field lookups. Takes a date value.
>
> Example:
>
> `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))`
> `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))`

As it says: "Takes a date value.". Thus `__date` is compared to a `datetime.date` object, not a `datetime.datetime` object.

Your `datetime.datetime` object is obviously cast to a `datetime.date` object under the hood.